# preferred way to update sqlite db in android

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite, sql-injection

Which way to use db.update is faster and better in android? ie: construct the entire where clause string along with where clause variable values OR make use of the 4th parameter for update by passing where clause variable values as a string array?

Does passing where clause variable values as a new string array protect against sql injection attacks?

```
  public boolean UpdateChannelSortKey(Channel c)
  {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("SortKey", c.SortKey);
        return this.db.update("Channels", cv, "ChannelID = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(c.ChannelID)}) > 0;
  }
```

OR

```
public boolean UpdateChannelSortKey(Channel c)
  {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("SortKey", c.SortKey);
        return this.db.update("Channels", cv, "ChannelID = " + c.ChannelID, null) > 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first way is preferable, because:

1) Yes, it protects against sql-injection attacks.

2) It is better to always use the prepared statements - not in android only, so you will obtain a good habit.

3) IMHO, it has higher readability.